# Videochat using Django? or other Python framework?

Tags: javascript, python, django, comet, videochat

i wanna make an application with videochat. Something like google chat, with text chat and an option to start live video chat.

What do you recommend to me? i don't know where i can start, help me please.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

I would start by using something else in your application. Once you've mastered using others and have become familiar with how they work, then perhaps explore how to make your own. I believe for now, the only way of really doing this is to use Flash in some form. I don't believe javascript can grab frames from webcams, but I'm not a javascript geek - maybe HTML5 has a facility for this.

Anyway, try something like these:

- http://mashable.com/2009/09/30/tinychat-p2p/
- http://www.infoworld.com/d/open-source-software/google-releases-video-chat-source-code-780

Or perhaps look around, with searches like this:
http://www.google.com/search?channel=fs&q=video+chat+open+source&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8